# How to get the width of wpf expander togglebutton in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to build a customcontrol where expandable rows are added to grid. In order to match the columns of the expandable row, I added another grid as expander header and content. However, the columns are slightly tilted to the right (see picture). I think it is because of the header size?

How do I access the width of the togglebutton code, so I can change the columndefinitions accordingly?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are 'Col1', 'Col2' etc real columns defined in XAML. 2. If I drew an imaginary vertical line just left of the 'Col1' text straight down, in your desired results would you expect the togglebutton to be on the left or on the right side of that line?

Comment: Also if you could post some XAML showing how you have things laid out it might help as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't:) Its all created at runtime, in several stacked loops. So There is not much xaml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this.

One would be trying to find the width of that togglebutton yourself by looking at [the control template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296(v=vs.100).aspx) and compensating - but this is unreliable as the template can change across .NET versions (and operating systems if I recall correctly) and is messy to implement anyway.

The second way is trying to programatically find the width and compensate that way, but that still requires digging into the control template (see issues above)

The third is to let the layout engine figure things out for you.  You can do this by [sharing the column width](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx) on columns 2-4, and setting the width of column 1 to "*". Doing this initially will yield undesired results however, because the Expander Header template has no way to set the HorizontalContentAlignment.

[image: First Try]

With a little of the above mentioned risk, you can fix that by digging around in the template via codebehind, [as described here](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/02/24/stretching-content-in-an-expander-header/) But its still not perfect yet.

[image: Closer]

Looks like there is a border or margin somewhere.  Lets set the BorderThickness of the expander to 0.

[image: Frustrating]

UGH! Better - (the whitespace is gone), but there is still a gap between our grid (red with black border) and the green in .NET 4.5.  I could not find the source of this gap in a reasonable amount of time, so I just set the Margin of the expander to 0,0,-1,0.  This might need to be compensated for inside the expander depending on content, and brings up suppressed memories of CSS hacks (XAML was suppose to be better, wasn't it?)

End Result:

[image: Final]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="800" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StretchedHeaderTemplate">
        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="Border_Loaded">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Margin="15">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MainLeft"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MainRight"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" SharedSizeGroup="Col2"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" SharedSizeGroup="Col3"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" SharedSizeGroup="Col4"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock>Col1</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock>Col2</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock>Col3</TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock>Col4</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">January</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">February</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center">March</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <Expander HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource StretchedHeaderTemplate}" Background="LightGreen" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,0,-1,0">
            <Expander.Header>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightCoral">
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col2"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col3"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col4"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock>Record1</TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock>02.05.2016</TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock>05.05.2017</TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock>340</TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Expander.Header>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Border_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Border root = (Border)sender;
        ContentPresenter presenter = (ContentPresenter)root.TemplatedParent;
        presenter.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**  This works, but you might want to consider overriding the control template for the Expander if you find any of it too messy.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! There were actually several problems:
- Scrollbars messed up the content of the expanders. Once remove, the content aligned fine. (I noticed after I posted, that this was a problem)
- I managed to stretch the header, so this works fine.
- However, I'm very new to xaml and wpf, so I had trouble with some parts of your solution. I took the shortcut and set the first column in the expander grid 34 px less, which works for now. I hope to fix this, once I gained some more knowledge about xaml, templates aso...

Comment: Glad you've got it figure out :)